# Win32 key translation code outputting unwanted key-presses

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-hook

I'm using the following code to get an unicode string of a keyboard state:

```
std::wstring App::DecodeMessage(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* kbHook) {
    // Clean up the keyboard state
    for(int i=0; i<256; ++i) keyboardMap[i] = 0;

    // Get the state of all the virtual keys
    GetKeyboardState(keyboardMap);

    // Then we get the current layout setting
    HKL kbdLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

    // We create the buffer to receive the unicode chars
    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer;
    buffer.resize(257);
    buffer.assign(257, L'\0');

    // And finally we translate all this to an unicode char
    int numberOfChars = ToUnicode(kbHook->vkCode, kbHook->scanCode, keyboardMap, &buffer[0], 256, 0);

    if(numberOfChars >= -1 && numberOfChars <= 0) return std::wstring(L"");

    return std::wstring(&buffer[0], numberOfChars);
}
```

My keyboard layout is US-INTL, and without the app running, when i press "'" (simple quote), and on a second keystroke i press "a", i get á. However, with this function, when i press "'" (simple quote again) i actually get ANOTHER single quote in whatever app i'm focused. Also, it doesn't seem to get the encoding right, as it won't record á. I'm clueless, can anyone help?

Comment: [`ToUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320.aspx): *The parameters supplied to the ToUnicode function might not be sufficient to translate the virtual-key code because a previous dead key is stored in the keyboard layout.*

Comment: @IInspectable I don't think that explains the fact that when i press a single quote with the app running, the focused app gets another quote. Like this:

*opens notepad*
*types '*

the output is " '' " when the app is running, and " ' " when the app is not

Comment: It explains the *"it doesn't seem to get the encoding right"* part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally sorted it out to not using ToUnicode. I ended up using the solution created by Marc-André Moreau, found available at http://keymagic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r112/trunk/KeyMagicDll/kbdext.cpp, if anyone is interested.

Comment: Michael Kaplan seems to come to the same conclusion: [He's dead (keys), Jim](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/01/19/355870.aspx). `ToUnicode[Ex]` doesn't handle dead keys very well.